# Why won't this ElasticSearch query work correctly?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed two websites (www.aaa.com and www.zzz.com) using the ElasticSearch River Web plugin.

My index has two fields: body and parentUrl.

When I run the following query, I am getting results where the parentUrl is http://www.zzz.com even though I am asking in my query to only show me results with http://www.aaa.com.

Here's the query:

```
POST /webindex/_search/
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                     "match": {
                       "body": "press"
                     }
                },
                {
                     "match" : {
                       "parentUrl": "http://www.aaa.com/"
                     }
                }
            ]
         }
    }
}
```

And here's the mapping:

```
{
  "my_web" : {
    "dynamic_templates" : [
      {
        "url" : {
          "match" : "url",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : "yes",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "method" : {
          "match" : "method",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : "yes",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "charSet" : {
          "match" : "charSet",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : "yes",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mimeType" : {
          "match" : "mimeType",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : "yes",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

Comment: Could you post the mappings of your index? If the parentUrl is indexed as "analyzed" field then this may be the problem. The analyzer breaks the url string in tokens and you most probably have 5 tokens [http, www, aaa, zzz, com] in the inverted index. Thus the match clause for url will match in both cases.

Comment: I added the mapping above, it appears that the url is not analyzed